# Проблема при построчном добавлении текста в файл

Tags: python

Скрипт по очереди добавляет в файл строки. Проблема в том что между строками появляются загаданные пробелы.

**Пример:**

```
_label_0 Оказание дополнительных реабилитационных услуг по реабилитации детей-инвалидов вследствие детского церебрального паралича и других патологий методом иппотерапии

_label_0 Строительство НИИ Детской онкологии и гематологии РОНЦ им. Н.Н. Блохина РАМН по адресу: г. Москва, Каширское шоссе, дом 24 (Поставка медицинского оборудования и мебели)

_label_0 Выполнение работ по ремонту имеющегося у Заказчика медицинского оборудования производства фирмы Maquet GmbH, Германия

_label_0 Поставка перчаток медицинских в 2019 году
```

**Предположение**

Я думаю что проблема в скрытых юникод символах

**часть кода с записью в файл:**

```
  str_to_write = str(url[1]) + " " + str(description_item.getText()) + "\r\n"
   if str_to_write != " ":
     with open("fortest.txt", "a", encoding='utf8') as f:
        f.write(str_to_write)
```

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `"\r\n"` писать просто `"\n"`

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: как вам  галочку поставить?

Comment: Какая система? Линукс?

Comment: windows, но так же планируется перенос на Линукс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вместо `"\r\n"` писать просто `"\n"`